# eCharts Datazoom causing elements to overlap grid

Tags: grid, zooming, overlap, echarts

I have built a series chart with the ability to zoom on both the `xAxis` and `yAxis`. Is there a way to prevent elements from "spilling" outside the grid while zooming?

[image: Elements outside of the grid when zoomed]

I played with the filter settings, and if I use 'empty' for the `yAxis` the fills for items are blank for any element approaching the edge of the grid, even if the bulk of the item is still on the chart. I have also tried:

```
axisLabel: {
    hideOverlap: true,
}
```

But elements still overlap the grid when zooming.

Comment: What are the pink stars ? Are they part of the series, graphics, custom or something else ? Could you share a simple working example of your problem (with the complete echart `option` object) ?